# How did the traffic for this particular question explode?

Tags: discussion

In less than 24 hours [this question got 7k views](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/34673/barbell-says-20kg-on-each-side-am-i-lifting-20-or-40kg) and shot up to my highest rated answer.

[My second highest rated answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/is-weight-loss-possible-without-cardio/24500#24500) has 2.5k views and it took over *two years* to get to that view count.

What happened traffic wise to create such a flood for such a rather odd and basic question, with plenty of other odd and basic questions appearing constantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It made it to the hot network questions list.  I don't know what pattern of activity got it onto the list in the first place, but as soon as you make that spotlight, the views and votes will pour in.

Comment: This. The HNQ always gets tons of views and votes.